# Prove that $P(n)$ holds for all $n \in \Bbb N^+$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than zero: $n \in \Bbb N^+$

The following statements are true:

1. $P(20)$
2. $P(n) \Leftrightarrow P(2n)\ \ \ for\ n < 20$
3. $P(n) \Leftrightarrow P(n-4)\ \ \ for\ n > 20$

**How can I prove, that $P(n)$ is true for all $n$** (That is clearly the case)? Especially, is it possible to prove it using mathematical induction?

I can prove it argumentatively, however I'm looking for a formal proof.

---

**Edit:** Brief argumentative proof: The statement is true for all multiples of 4 greater than 20, since they are so often reduced by 4 until they are equal to 20. Multiples of 4 less than 20 are so often doubled until they're greater than 20. Of course, those numbers remain multiples of 4.

Numbers that are not multiples of 4 are repeatedly doubled and reduced by 4. At the latest, when they have been doubled twice, they're also multiples of 4, since this is equivalent to a multiplication of four.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Edit the question to show us your "argumentative" proof. If the logic of what you write is correct then it is a proof, perhaps forma enough. If it's not someone here may be able to help you.

Comment: Can you tell us what is $P$ ?

Comment: You *can't*.  How can you prove that $P(1)$ holds?  (2) only reduces $n$ by a half, so you'll end up with $P(5)$, and you *can't* reduce it further.

Comment: @GNUSupporter $P(1) = P(2) = P(4) = \dotsc = P(32) = P(28) = P(24) = P(20)$

Comment: @DanielFischer I see.  Thank you for your comment

Comment: @EthanBolker Done. I'm sure, that the logic is correct. I'm asking this question only for personal interest in a mathematical proof.

Comment: Once you have $P(17), P(18), P(19), P(20)$, it follows by 3. that $P(n)$ holds for all $n > 16$. Then $2$ shows $P(n)$ for all $n > 8$, then $n > 4$, then $n > 2$, then $n > 1$, then $n > 0$.

Comment: If you expand the last paragraph along the lines suggested in comments or @ArturRiazanov answer you're done.

Comment: What exactly is *unclear* about my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be proven that for any $m$ such that $4 | m$ if  $\forall n > m\colon P(n) = P(n - 4)$; $\forall n < m\colon P(n) = P(2n)$ and $P(m)$ then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\colon P(n)$.

If $\ell \le {m \over 2}$ then $P(\ell) = P(2^k \cdot \ell)$ where $k$ is the minimum number such that $2^k \cdot \ell \ge m$. Clearly $4 | 2^k \cdot \ell$. Hence $P(2^k \cdot \ell) = P(2^k \cdot \ell - 4) = \ldots = P(m)$. Therefore $P(\ell)$ is true for all $\ell \le {m \over 2}$. Then $P\left({m \over 2}-1\right) \implies P(m - 2) \implies P(m+2)$.

Thus for all even numbers $k \ge m$, $P(k)$ is true. Let ${m \over 2} < \ell \le m$. $m < 2\ell \le 2m$, $P(\ell) = P(2\ell)$. Since $2\ell$ is an even number $\ge m$, $P(2\ell)$ is true. Hence so is $P(\ell)$.

Therefore we've proved that $P(\ell)$ is true for all $\ell \le m$. Then for arbitrary $n > m$, $P\left(n - \lceil{n-m \over 4}\rceil \cdot 4\right)$ is true hence so is $P(n)$.

Edited, in the original answer, I've only done that for $m=20$.

Comment: Are you claiming that this answers the question of whether $P(n)$ can be proven for all positive integers $n$?

Comment: I ask because while most of the cases can be pieced together from your post, you omit mentioning $P(5)$ and $P(10)$.  While these can be filled in, it seems to me that the Answer would be improved by stating clearly that it can be proven for all positive integers and organizing the facts around that conclusion in a more systematic way.

Comment: Yes, thank you, let me do it.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort! Yet, shouldn't it be $P(n-4)$ rather than $P(n+4)$ in your introductory phrase?

Comment: Right, it should, thank you. I've used the property with the minus.